# How to use MERGE-statement with VARBINARY data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to get one of the MERGE statements to work. See below code snippet:

```
DECLARE @PipelineRunID VARCHAR(100) = 'testestestestest'

MERGE [TGT].[AW_Production_Culture] as [Target]
USING [SRC].[AW_Production_Culture] as [Source]
ON [Target].[MD5Key] = [Source].[MD5Key]
WHEN MATCHED AND [Target].[MD5Others] != [Source].[MD5Others]
THEN UPDATE SET
     [Target].[CultureID] = [Source].[CultureID]
    ,[Target].[ModifiedDate] = [Source].[ModifiedDate]
    ,[Target].[Name] = [Source].[Name]
    ,[Target].[MD5Others] = [Source].[MD5Others]
    ,[Target].[PipelineRunID] = @PipelineRunID
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT VALUES (
     [Source].[AW_Production_CultureKey]
    ,[Source].[CultureID]
    ,[Source].[ModifiedDate]
    ,[Source].[Name]
    ,@PipelineRunID
    ,[Source].[MD5Key]
    ,[Source].[MD5Others]);
```

When I try and run this query I receive the following error:

```
Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 16
Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

The only VARBINARY column types are `MD5Key` and `MD5Others`. As they are both linked to their corresponding columns I don't understand why my error message indicates there is a VARCHAR problem involved. Does anybody understand how and why I should use a CONVERT() function here?

Thanks!

--EDIT: Schema definitions

```
CREATE VIEW [SRC].[AW_Production_Culture]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
as
SELECT
     CAST(CONCAT('',[CultureID]) as VARCHAR(100)) as [AW_Production_CultureKey]
    ,CAST(HASHBYTES('MD5',CONCAT('',[CultureID])) as VARBINARY(16)) as [MD5Key]
    ,CAST(HASHBYTES('MD5',CONCAT([ModifiedDate],'|',[Name])) as VARBINARY(16)) as [MD5Others]
    ,[CultureID],[ModifiedDate],[Name]
FROM
    [SRC].[tbl_AW_Production_Culture]
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE [TGT].[AW_Production_Culture](
    [AW_Production_CultureKey] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [CultureID] [nchar](6) NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MD5Key] [varbinary](16) NOT NULL,
    [MD5Others] [varbinary](16) NOT NULL,
    [RecordValidFrom] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    [RecordValidUntil] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
    [PipelineRunID] [varchar](36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [MD5Key] ASC
    )WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
        PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([RecordValidFrom], [RecordValidUntil])
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    WITH
    (
    SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON ( HISTORY_TABLE = [TGT].[AW_Production_Culture_History] )
    )
```

Comment: Check the datatypes and positions of the source/target columns - and perhaps update the question with the schema definition of your source and target tables

Comment: Change your `INSERT` clause to explicitly list destination column names. I think that’s the problem: your inserted values are going into the wrong columns. Always use named columns when inserting!

Comment: Also, when using `MERGE` you should use `HOLDLOCK` (Or a more suitable lock, if applicable) - otherwise you’ll run into concurrency issues. `MERGE` is not concurrency-safe by default!

Comment: As Dai said, use an explicit column list for your `INSERT`. At the moment you're trying to insert `@PipelineRunId` into your `MD5Key` column.

Comment: Thanks for helping out guys, it needed the columns explicitly naming. I am unable to select one of your comments as answering the question. Dai if you would like me to accept your answer please post a separate comment (not under this thread) Hopefully then I can accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Reposting my comment as an answer for the sweet, sweet, internet points:</sub>

- You're getting that error because your `varbinary` value is being inserted into a `varchar` column. As your columns have the correct types already then it means your `INSERT` clause has mismatched columns.

  - As it is, your `MERGE` statement is not explicitly listing the destination columns - you should always explicitly list columns in production code so that your DML queries won't break if columns are added or reordered or marked `HIDDEN`.
  - So to fix this, change your `INSERT` clause to explicitly list destination column names.
- Also, when using `MERGE` you should use `HOLDLOCK` (Or a more suitable lock, if applicable) - otherwise you’ll run into concurrency issues. `MERGE` is not concurrency-safe by default!
- Minor nit-picks that are largely subjective:

  - I personally prefer avoiding `[escapedName]` wherever possible and prefer using short table aliases.

    - e.g. use `s` and `t` instead of `[Source]` and `[Target]`.
  - "Id" (for "identity" or "identifier") is an abbreviation, not an acronym - so it should be cased as `Id` and not `ID`.
  - Consider using an `OUTPUT` clause to help diagnose/debug issues too.

So I'd write it like so:

```
DECLARE @PipelineRunId VARCHAR(100) = 'testestestestest'

MERGE INTO
    tgt.AW_Production_Culture WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS t
USING
    src.AW_Production_Culture AS s ON t.MD5Key = s.MD5Key

WHEN MATCHED AND t.MD5Others != s.MD5Others THEN UPDATE SET

    t.CultureId     = s.CultureId,
    t.ModifiedDate  = s.ModifiedDate,
    t.Name          = s.Name,
    t.MD5Others     = s.MD5Others,
    t.PipelineRunID = @PipelineRunId

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT
    (
        AW_Production_CultureKey,
        CultureId,
        ModifiedDate,
        [Name],
        PipelineRunId,
        MD5Key,
        MD5Others
    )
    VALUES
    (
        s.AW_Production_CultureKey,
        s.CultureId,
        s.ModifiedDate,
        s.[Name],
        @PipelineRunId,
        s.MD5Key,
        s.MD5Others
    )
OUTPUT
    $action AS [Action],
    inserted.*,
    deleted.*;
```